# how to fix Undefined variable: Products in view blade eloquent laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I didn't know why `undefined variable`, I've made controller, model and view. I've included the compact in the controller for the variable.

this is my controller

```
public function product(){
    $products = Product::all();
    // print_r($products);
    return view('views.product', compact('products'));
}
```

model

```
class Product extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['product_name', 'price', 'kategori'];
}
```

and view

```
@foreach ($Products as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$post->product_name}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

route

```
Route::get('/product', 'AdminController@product')->name('Product');
```

Please help me I don't know why this undefined variable, cause I've included compact in my controller

Comment: products is different from Products

Comment: change $Products to $products in foreach

Comment: `compact('products'));` & `$Products`, are you able to see the difference between two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo mistake. Edit your view file. I think it will work.

```
//$products instead of $Products 
@foreach ($products as $post)
<tr>
   <td>{{$post->product_name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

**change:**

```
@foreach ($Products as $post)
```

**to:**

```
@foreach ($products as $post)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
//$products instead of $Products 
@foreach ($products as $post)
<tr>
   <td>{{$post->product_name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach

if above code is not work then use below code

@if(!empty($products))
  @foreach ($products as $post)
  <tr>
     <td>{{$post->product_name}}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
@endif
```